# How grab urls from text file which have .com .org .net domain with unix command

Tags: unix, awk, sed

I need a regex for copying domain names from text files. In text files, the domains look like

```
site.com   - org name - title
site.net   - other name - another title
HTTP://target.ca - ca site - ca title
```

From this text file I need

```
site.com
site.net
target.ca
```

I try `sed 's/\.com\/.*/.com/' file.txt` but this command only give me .com domain but I need all the domain name. Pls, help me out.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***1st solution:*** With your shown samples, please try following `awk` code. Simple explanation would be, setting field separator as space OR `/` for all the lines and in main block of `awk` program checking if line starts with `HTTP:` then print 3rd field else print 1st field to get required values as per requirements.

```
awk -F' |/' '/^HTTP:/{print $3;next} {print $1}' Input_file
```

---

---

***2nd solution:*** Using `sed` please try following code. Using `-E` option of `-E` to enable ERE(extended regular expressions) and capturing group capability of `sed` here. Here is the [Online demo](https://regex101.com/r/l7XaBw/1) for used regex in `sed` code.

```
sed -E 's/^(HTTP:\/\/)?([^[:space:]]+).*$/\2/'  Input_file
```

---

---

***3rd solution:*** Using GNU `grep` here with its `\K` option which allows us to match things with regex and forget/neglect them while printing. Here is the [Online demo](https://regex101.com/r/lpQXag/1) for used regex in `grep` solution.

```
grep -oP '^(HTTP:\/\/)?\K([^[:space:]]+)'  Input_file
```

Comment: Bro,
When the text file with `https://` or `https://www.` or `www.` or `http://www.` then which command I will use?

Comment: @MuhammadImran the "edit" button under your question to clarify your requirements and provide more truly representative sample input and expected output that demonstrate all of your requirements.

Comment: @MuhammadImran, I would like to request you to **Open a new question** with all details and your tried code because of you edit your this question now(after quite sometime) then **none of my answers will make sense**. So kindly open a NEW question and we will discuss it there, cheers. Request you not to edit this answer please.

Answer (score 0):

I would harness GNU `sed` for this task following way, let `file.txt` content be

```
site.com   - org name - title
site.net   - other name - another title
HTTP://target.ca - ca site - ca title
```

then

```
sed -e 's|^http://||i' -e 's|[[:space:]].*||' file.txt
```

gives output

```
site.com
site.net
target.ca
```

Explanation: I inform GNU `sed` to apply two changes, 1st is to replace `http://` at begin of line (`^`) with empty line acting in case-insensitive way (`i`), 2nd is to replace first whitespace character and everything beyond it with empty string. Observe that I use `|` as delimiters and therefore I do no need to escape `/` character.

*(tested in GNU sed 4.2.2)*
(tested in

Answer (score 0):

Another simple `awk` solution:

```bash
awk '{sub(/^HTTP:\/\//, ""); print $1}' file

site.com
site.net
target.ca
```